AWS CloudFront Signed URL For Uploads And Downloads
I want to give both, read and write access to my AWS CloudFront distribution but via separate signed urls. Aka a signed url only for reading and a signed url only for writing. Is this possible? Because the NPM package @aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer only has the getSignedUrl function which does not seem to have this feature. Thanks.

Hey, I am talking about the CloudFront signer, not the S3 signer. Aka @aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer package. I don't see any option to specify the operation in this package.

Are you hoping to upload to S3 via CloudFront? If so, you can use S3 transfer acceleration and create pre-signed URLs for acceleration endpoints afaik (example here).

Yeah that's the only option it seems.
